# COALESCE returning NULL when there are no records

Tags: mysql

When running the following query on a `device_id` that has no entries in the `inv_zfs_replication` table the result is a NULL value. How can I make the 2nd sub-query return a zero if there aren't any records?

```
SELECT
    (
        (
            SELECT
                SUM(s.quota)
            FROM
                `inv_zfs_share` s
            JOIN `inv_zfs_project` p2 ON s.project_id = p2.id
            WHERE
                p2.device_id = p.device_id
            GROUP BY
                p2.pool_id
        ) + (
            SELECT
                COALESCE (SUM(quota), 0)
            FROM
                inv_zfs_replication
            WHERE
                device_id = p.device_id
            GROUP BY
                pool_id
        )
    ) AS 'Quota Total'
FROM
    inv_zfs_pool p
WHERE
    p.device_id = 626
```

Comment: BTW, I've also tried replacing `COALESCE` with `IFNULL` without any luck.

Comment: The two `GROUP BY pool_id` are either redundant or could cause error when you run the query and a subquery has more than 1 different `pool_id`. Inline subqueries must return either 1 or 0 values.

Comment: They aren't redundant, if you look they're on different tables.

Comment: I meant they are both and individually redundant. For example in table `inv_zfs_replication`, is it possible that you have 2 rows with same `device_id` but different `pool_id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scalar subqueries that return no rows have a return "value" of `NULL` ... so all you need to do is coerce that `NULL` to a 0 directly outside the subquery with `IFNULL()`:

```
SELECT
    (
        (
            SELECT
                SUM(s.quota)
            FROM
                `inv_zfs_share` s
            JOIN `inv_zfs_project` p2 ON s.project_id = p2.id
            WHERE
                p2.device_id = p.device_id
            GROUP BY
                p2.pool_id
        ) + 
         IFNULL( -- add this, here
           (
            SELECT
                SUM(quota)
            FROM
                inv_zfs_replication
            WHERE
                device_id = p.device_id
            GROUP BY
                pool_id
        )
      ,0) -- and add this, here
    ) AS 'Quota Total'
FROM
    inv_zfs_pool p
WHERE
    p.device_id = 626;
```

Comment: This was the simplest answer, thanks @michael-sqlbot.

Answer (score 2):

Put it outside. I think it will work

```
        SELECT COALESCE(
              (
              SELECT SUM(quota)
        FROM
            inv_zfs_replication
        WHERE
            device_id = p.device_id
        GROUP BY
            pool_id),0) AS 'Quota Total'
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not work, because there is no row to return, so there is no column to COALESCE.  If this is what you need, then you will need to force a row to be included.  E.g.

```
        SELECT SUM(SumQuota) AS SumQuota -- Outer summation needed to 'coalesce' values 
        FROM (
        SELECT
           SUM(quota) AS SumQuota
        FROM
            inv_zfs_replication
        WHERE
            device_id = p.device_id
        GROUP BY
            pool_id
        UNION ALL  -- Forces a 0 value row to exist
        SELECT 0 AS SumQuota) AS ForceRow
```

Since you add 0 to the SUM, which might not exist, then you get either a 0 or the sum + 0, which is, of course no change.